# how to impute missing value in python using some condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, numpy-ndarray

I have a datafrae like this :
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwq84.png

```
|Name   |last_update    |New date   |visited    |date
|Ravi   |22-04-2010     |22-04-2010 |abc        |24-04-2010
|Ravi   |27-0-2010      |28-04-2010 |xyz        |
|Rajesh |22-06-2012     |22-07-2012 |yyy        25-08-2012
|Rajesh |24-02-2014     |25-04-2014 |zzz
```

Here i have to replace missing value in `date` column with `New date` and if we have date missing for eg: Rajesh, we will check does Rajesh have any entry in visited column with name `yyy` if yes then his missing date will get replace with `last_update`. How can i achieve this.

Final output should be this:

```
|Name   |last_update    |New date   |visited    |date
|Ravi   |22-04-2010     |22-04-2010 |abc        |24-04-2010
|Ravi   |27-0-2010      |28-04-2010 |xyz        |28-04-2010
|Rajesh |22-06-2012     |22-07-2012 |yyy        |25-08-2012
|Rajesh |24-02-2014     |25-04-2014 |zzz        |24-02-2014
```

Comment: Can you pls help explain what is required? For all rows, the 'date' column should have the same value as 'New date', EXCEPT where visited = 'yyy', in which case, it should have the value that is in 'last_update' column? Is this the ask?

Comment: SO, if date column has missing value then missing value should get replaced with new date. but if a person has multiple entries and in one of his entries column visited has value yyy then for that person missing value for column date should gat replaced with last update

Comment: Please do not post such clarifications in the comments; edit & update your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working with pandas and dataframe is named df (import df again/restart runtime)

```
#for visited site
df.loc[(df['visited'] == 'yyy') & (df['date'].isnull),'date']= df['last_update']
 
#for missing values of date
df.loc[df['date'].isnull,'date'] = df['New date']
```

Comment: so this code is replacing the value of date with last update if 'yyy' is present in visited column. but the task is if we have date missing for rajesh now we will check does rajesh has any entry in visited column with name yyy if yes then his missing date will get replace with latest update